# Joomla+Phoca Gallery+Site goes down when I enable thumbnail creation

Tags: php, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have phoca gallery installed and was working fine before yesterday.From yesterday I was getting an error of out of memory. So I set the upload limit to infinite. Now after that when I enabled Thumbnail creation, the whole site goes down, and an error was show in some line number 212 on the file ImageMagik.php . But as I have read in the user manual Phoca gallery uses GD Library rather than ImageMagik. Can anyone suggest me what could be the problem behind this. I want to solve it as soon as possible, and due to this client has asked to look for another solution than this. Please help!

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? The exact error would be nice as well.

Comment: Did you enable error_reporting in the Joomla! Configuration? Try switching it to a lower level maybe? Also check that your Server configuration is compatible with Joomla! This can be done in the Administration Panel

Answer (score 1):

this is mostly caused by memory error. In fact, there are two options you can do:

- increase memory limmit on your server (if you are able to do)
- or remove or reduce the size of images on the server.

See the Info panel in Phoca Gallery, there you will see the recommendation for the Phoca Gallery settings.

You can try to enable Pagination Thumbnail creating which saves a lot of memory while searching for images which do not have thumbnails yet (automatically thumbnail creating)

Yes, Phoca Gallery uses GD library, the imagemagic is an internal function where Phoca Gallery tries to use GD library to create thumbnails.

Jan